# Ошибка по CORS при отправке запроса

Tags: javascript, php, get, fetch, cors

После создания  API  запросы с постмэна уходят на ура, но при создании запроса в стороннем приложении выдает  ошибку по  CORS .

[image]

заголовки в  index.php в  APi  прописаны

[image]

код самого запроса

[image]

[image]

network

[image]

Comment: смотреть нужно не запрос, а ответ сервера. Есть ли в ответе заголовки с Allow-Origin? И не нужно показывать php-код сервера, вы покажите, что он их реально выдаёт. Например, через тот же postman

Comment: с постмэна все норм приходит, заголовки с него на последнем скрине

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда на какой запрос ругается браузер? В некоторый случаях бывает, что браузер дополнительно присылает запрос методом OPTION, а вас сервер неадекватно его может обработать. Тогда будете получать ошибку cors, несмотря на то, что все нужные заголовки присутствуют

Comment: ругается на простой гет запрос, который на втором скрине, левых запросов вроде не обнаружено

Comment: Тогда последний вариант. Отправляйте в заголовках вместо "\*" названия разрешённых методов и заголовков. С заголовком `Credentials: true` "\*" не очень хорошо работает

Answer (score 0):

обнаружив через постмэн, что приходит два заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, удалил такой заголовок из  index.php и все заработало.

Также прописал методы в Access-Control-Allow-Methods